# How can I close or remove the circle that is contained in my svg?

Tags: html, svg

I am new to the svg theme, and I would like to know if it is possible to remove the white circle from my bookmark.

[image]

This is the code of my svg:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
  <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
  <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 485.213 485.212" style="enable-background:new 0 0 485.213 485.212;" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
    <path d="M242.606,0C142.124,0,60.651,81.473,60.651,181.955c0,40.928,13.504,78.659,36.31,109.075l145.646,194.183L388.252,291.03   c22.808-30.416,36.31-68.146,36.31-109.075C424.562,81.473,343.089,0,242.606,0z M242.606,303.257   c-66.989,0-121.302-54.311-121.302-121.302c0-66.989,54.313-121.304,121.302-121.304c66.991,0,121.302,54.315,121.302,121.304   C363.908,248.947,309.598,303.257,242.606,303.257z" fill="#d82c62" stroke="#d82c62"/>
  </g>
  </svg>
```

I want that the circle does not exist, that is to say that the figure is like this image:

[image]

thank you very much.

https://jsfiddle.net/L10m35ny/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This svg is a path so the circle is contained somewhere in

```
<svg><path d="here you have svg path"/></svg>
```

The easiest way to do it is to open svg file in any editor like Corel Draw, Adobe Ilustrator or other available for free (it's a vector image so it won't open in paint). You should create a new map marker and export to new svg file. You will get completely different path.

---

**UPDATE**
This is the svg you are looking for.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 26900 35810" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill="#D82C62" d="m13406 35810c424-340 9325-12335 10071-13340 1180-1589 2146-2848 2818-5086 2756-9189-4320-17352-12785-17384-9099-34-15490 8788-12948 17248 980 3261 3947 6682 6125 9588l5018 6693c517 689 1266 1582 1701 2281z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: how did he do it...?

Comment: How did I do it? You showed me what map marker you need and I made a very simple edit in Corel Draw (it's a program to design vector graphics). I created a new vector and saved as new svg file. At the end I minified everything (removed comments, xml, metadata etc). It is recommended to do this way simply because svg is really complicated and you need some visual way to edit images. I hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

simply Right click on your svg and open with notepad

and replace this code

```
    <svg width="485.213" height="485.212" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <title>background</title>
  <rect fill="none" id="canvas_background" height="402" width="582" y="-1" x="-1"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <g id="farthardly">
   <path id="svg_1" stroke="#d82c62" fill="#d82c62" d="m242.606,0c-100.482,0 -181.955,81.473 -181.955,181.955c0,40.928 13.504,78.659 36.31,109.075l145.646,194.183l145.645,-194.183c22.808,-30.416 36.31,-68.146 36.31,-109.075c0,-100.482 -81.473,-181.955 -181.956,-181.955zm0,303.257c-66.989,0 -121.302,-54.311 -121.302,-121.302c0,-66.989 54.313,-121.304 121.302,-121.304c66.991,0 121.302,54.315 121.302,121.304c0,66.992 -54.31,121.302 -121.302,121.302z"/>
  </g>
  <ellipse stroke="#d82c62" ry="121.999997" rx="126.999996" id="svg_2" cy="180.606014" cx="240.106494" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#d82c62"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

output

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBzDR.png)

Comment: thanks but, I think I did not make myself understood. I updated the question

Comment: If I resize the svg by modifying the size, would it be damaged?

Comment: i just added ellipse over path , ellipse is relative to svg so it will adjust with svg size